# What SQL statement do I need to insert data into multiple rows that are currently 'null'?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1064

I have data in this format, that I want to enter into a column in my mysql database. The column i created is empty with null values.

```
[(1958000,),
(261250,),
(205480,),
(140580,),
(804320,),
(652653,),
(484990,),]
```

I am using python to insert data using the following code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO city(Population) VALUES(%s)"
new_column_data = The data I listed above. 

mycursor.executemany(sql, new_column_data)
```

When I run this, It inserted data into rows starting below all the 'null' values in Population.

Would something like this work?

```
sql = "INSERT INTO city(Population) VALUES(%s) WHERE Population = 'null'"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To change data of existing rows, you'd do an `UPDATE`, something like `UPDATE city SET population = 666 WHERE id = 123;`. `INSERT` is for creating new rows.

Comment: Unless you have the literal text "null" in your column you mean `WHERE x IS NULL` for any given column `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest solution for you is to remove the `NULL` columns before inserting the new data.

You would have to do this by running something like:

`DELETE c FROM city AS c WHERE c.Population IS NULL`

Then run your `INSERT`.

However, if you are trying to `UPDATE` existing records in `city` whose `Population` field is `NULL`, then you need to write a completely different statement.

Your data set will need to include a key, kind of like updating a Python dictionary.

```
dataset = 
[(1958000,<key_value>),
(261250,<key_value>),
(205480,<key_value>),
(140580,<key_value>),
(804320,<key_value>),
(652653,<key_value>),
(484990,<key_value>),]
```

Using these tuples, you will need to create an update statement. How this works depends on the Python library you are using. But something along the lines of this:

```
WITH ds = dataset: 
    statement = UPDATE c SET c.Population = ds.<population_value> WHERE c.<key_column> = ds.<key_value>
    mysql.update(statment,ds)
```